# drawing a rectangle with a string

Tags: string, matlab, drawing

I have a string like below:

> A = AREA ( -364320 -364320 ) ( 365640 365640 ) ;

now I want to draw a rectangle with A sting position in MATLAB.
I use this code to draw a rectangle:

```
rectangle('Position',[-364320 -364320 364320 364320],'FaceColor',[0 .9 .8])
```

but I want to draw it with using A string. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Directly you cannot use, however you can use [`strsplit`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [`str2num`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to split the string and convert it to numbers.
However, as [Wolfie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336687/2107764) pointed, better to use [`str2double`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html).

The code gets:

```
A =' AREA ( -364320 -364320 ) ( 365640 365640 ) ';
b=strsplit(A)
b =
  1×11 cell array
  Columns 1 through 8
    ''    'AREA'    '('    '-364320'    '-364320'    ')'    '('    '365640'
  Columns 9 through 11
    '365640'    ')'    ''
a_array=str2double(b([4 5 8 9]));
rectangle('Position',a_array,'FaceColor',[0 .9 .8])
```

Note that you may need to see if you have empty spaces in your `b` variable in case you have a slightly different string.

Original Code using `str2num`:

```
A =' AREA ( -364320 -364320 ) ( 365640 365640 ) ';
b=strsplit(A,{'(',')'})
b =
  1×5 cell array
    ' AREA '    ' -364320 -364320 '    ' '    ' 365640 365640 '    ' '
a_array=str2num([b{2} b{4}]);
rectangle('Position',a_array,'FaceColor',[0 .9 .8])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `regexp` with the `'match'` option to directly extract the numbers like so

```
% Extract strings which match:
%    -?  means 0 or 1 - signs
%    \d+ means 1 or more digits
% Using the 'match' argument returns the matching strings, rather than their indices
% Use str2double to convert from array of strings to numerical array
B = str2double(regexp(A, '-?\d+', 'match'));
% Create the rectangle
rectangle('Position', B, 'FaceColor', [0 .9 .8])
```

It's good to use `str2double` instead of `str2num`, because it is doesn't use `eval` under the hood.

This method simply picks out the numeric values, regardless of the format of your string.

Comment: Didn't know the problem of  `str2num`, so i adjusted my answer accordingly!

Comment: @Guto learn something new every day! From the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html): *"The str2num function does not convert string or cell arrays, and is sensitive to spacing around + and - operators. In addition, str2num uses the eval function, which can cause unintended side effects when the input includes a function name. To avoid these issues, use str2double."*